# Access HTML element later in document through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I am just starting out with JavaScript and I have a simple code that sends a value to an element with id `p`. I am currently declaring this function in a `<script>` in the `<head>` element of my document.

```
function writeP(resultSet) {
        document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = resultSet.length;
    };

    writeP(results);
```

When I have this listed within the `<head>` element and run the webpage, firebug throws this error at me: `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`.

However, if I move the code block into a `<script>` tag beneath the element and then reload the webpage, no problems and the script works as it should. Is there any reason for this, and a way I could make this work so I wouldn't have to define my functions beneath the element or include a `onload` on my body element?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is that by the time your launch js code, DOM is not yet prepared, and JS can't find such element in DOM.

You can use `window.onload` ([docs on W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)) trigger to fire your functions after all elements are ready. It's same as having onload property on body element, but is more clear, as you can define it in your js code, not in html.

Answer (score -1):

JS evaluates syncronically. Therefore, it does matter WHEN you declare the function. In this case, you're declaring it before the element actually exists.

Second, when you declare a function with that syntax, it does get eval'd inmediately. If you declared, instead

```
var    writeP=function(resultSet) {
    document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = resultSet.length;
};
```

you could save just the call to the end of the Doc, and leave the declaration at the beggining.

However, I would advise you to read a few jQuery tutorials to learn easier ways to deal with dom manipulation. Nobody runs raw JS for that task anymore.

jQuery includes an useful call to document ready event, which will save you a lot of headaches and is -IMHO- more efficient than the onload event. In this case, you would include the jQuery library somewhere in your code

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then add

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var writeP=function(resultSet) {
        jQuery('#p').html(resultSet.length);
    };
    writeP(resultSet);
});
</script>
```

just about anywhere in your document or an external js file, as it suits you.

Comment: Anybody cares to tell me why I got a neg?

Comment: `JS evaluates syncronically` has a typo and is incorrect. JS makes heavy use of callback functions executing asynchronous.
Declaring the function before the element exists is not a problem.
Declaring the named function is perfectly fine -- what do you mean by `it does get eval'd inmediately`?
The function certainly does not get invoked at that point.